# Check for child key/value pairs in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to identify if my JSON feed has child key/value pairs and handle them differently. what i mean is:

```
{ 
    "dashboard" :[
    {
        "name": "",
        "image": "",
        "description":"",
        "linkurl":"" },

    {
        "name": "",
        "image": "",
        "description":"",
        "linkurl":""
        },
    "related" : [
    {
        "name": "",
        "image": "",
        "description":"",
        "linkurl":""
        },
    {
        "name": "",
        "image": "",
        "description":"",
        "linkurl":""
        }]
  ]
```

How do i identify that this JSON has those child ("related") key/value pairs?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ Your JSON is mal-formed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After parsing the JSON string into a JavaScript object (see greengit's answer), you have three options:

- `typeof obj.related !== 'undefined'`
- `obj.related !== undefined`. Be careful when using the `undefined` variable, it can be changed by other scripts. If you are using it, make sure to wrap your code in anonymous function that sets it to a correct value - see [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#core.undefined) about that, under "Handling Changes to the Value of undefined"
- `'related' in obj`

IIRC, using `in` should be the fastest

**update** I remember it the other way around - `in` is the **slowest** way of doing that, by a large margin (98%!). Also, using `typeof obj.key !== 'undefined'` is much faster  than `obj.key !== undefined` (the latter is 80% slower). See http://jsperf.com/in-vs-not-undefined.

Comment: I want to make it a favorite answer... :(

Answer (score 2):

Convert JSON into a JS object and see if what you want is `undefined`.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json_string);

if ( obj.related == undefined ) {
  ...
```