# how can i test if elements are in json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to check if an element is in json data.

JSON data

```
{
    "status": {
        "carts": [
            {
                "service": "page-mailer",
                "running": "",
                "last success": "2015-05-07 09:35:31"
            }
        ],
        "pages": [
            {
                "service": "page-mailer",
                "running": "",
                "last success": "2015-05-07 09:35:31"
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
                "service": "page-mailer",
                "running": "",
                "last success": "2015-05-07 09:35:31"
            }
        ],
        "integrations": [],
        "service": [
            {
                "service": "page-mailer",
                "running": "",
                "last success": "2015-05-07 09:35:31"
            }
        ],
        "smtp": [
            {
                "Server": "myserver"
            }
        ],
        "servers": []
    },
    "timing": "2ms"
}
```

Something like,

```
if(carts){}  
if(pages){} etc
```

i am using jquery `getJSON();`

Comment: Duplicate- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295386/how-can-i-check-if-a-value-is-a-json-object

Comment: `if(data && data.status && data.status.carts)`

Comment: What else can it be ? This could also work: `if (typeof data == 'object') {}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for child key/value pairs in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104061/check-for-child-key-value-pairs-in-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work for you

```
if(data && data.status && data.status.carts){
   console.log("Exist")
}
```

Comment: He's using `$.getJSON`, so he doesn't need to call `JSON.parse()`, it's already parsed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
var data = {"status": { "carts": ....... } }
```

Then to check if `carts` exists you write:

```
if( data && data.status && data.status.carts ) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i believe my question didn't cover the part to find out if there are any records in carts or not. I want to execute if(data.status && data.status.carts){} only if it is not empty. would this condition work for that?

Comment: Yes, it would -- that's what it checks.

Comment: You need to check using `if(data && data.status && data.status.carts && data.status.carts.length)`. But if `data.status.carts` is always defined (even empty), you could just check for `if(data.status.carts.length)`